# Why is this question about unit testing off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How do I unit test the "exists" validation rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235646/how-do-i-unit-test-the-exists-validation-rule)

I don't understand why it is being voted closed and downvoted. If it is a poor question then that is another matter, but I can't improve it without feedback.

Comment: You have two downvotes , one upvote, and with 3 close votes on the question. It is not even closed, and you are discussing it on meta ?

Comment: @Habib There's a senior (by rep) member claiming the question is off topic in the comments. I think that's reason enough to ask about it on Meta. And even if it wasn't, what's the problem? Brian is just asking for clarifications, isn't that what Meta's for?

Comment: I would assume you got the flak and the downvotes for the 1st version of the question.  Deservedly.  The edit makes it a little better but it is still pretty unclear what exactly you need help with.

Comment: If you add the code which shows your unit test and where you try to mock or hook up the database it would be much more direct understandable. Now I have to envision the lines of code your looking at.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a laravel expert nor willing to become one but the first revision of your question was just a paraghraph of text describing  "an actual problem with actual code in an actual implementation."

*Is that unit test code many more characters than the paragraph of text you produced?*

When confronted with the comments you decided to respond with a revision adding even more text. That makes it looks like a theoretical discussion about how to unit test code that requires a database. So this edit only adds to the already planted idea that you're not having a practical issue with a handfull lines of code.

I do understand that for you and other OP's their problem is clear and in context, you're looking at your code right? But keep in mind that I have to build-up your context and perceive your code issue to come up with an answer.

*Only words is not a great way to convey an actual problem in a few lines of code*